# jQuery count live elements in a page by class

Tags: jquery

I have this function that will have to delete an element if the total of the selected elements is `> 1`

This is the function that I am using:

```
$(".delete").livequery(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var count = $(this).length;
            if (count > 1) {
                $(this).closest('#addBox').children('.show_hide').remove();
                $(this).closest('div.col_full').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that the elements will be `cloned` in the page every once in a while, this is why I am using `livequery`, but unfortunately this is not working at all.
The target element simply get not deleted even when there are more than 1.

Thanks for any help

Comment: When are you running the function, on pageload ?

Comment: Can you show the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)/representative HTML you're working with? And *which* elements are being cloned/deleted?

Comment: var count always will be equal 1 as long as you can only click one element at a time (because it is inside click event handler)

Comment: @matty I already tried outside but no difference at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prblem was that I was referring to the same instance. This works

```
$(".delete").livequery(function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var count =  $(".delete").length;
            if (count > 1) {
                $(this).closest('#addBox').children('.show_hide').remove();
                $(this).closest('div.col_full').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```